# <?php echo $this->pagination->creaerte_links(); ?> Pagination not working in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

i am newbie in codeigniter and i want to apply pagination on my table. i followed a tutorial but on view my pagination is not seen. my table has already six rows of data. i am getting successfully all data but pagination not working.

here is my controller code:

```
class news_cont extends CI_Controller
{
   public function __construct()
        {
        parent::__construct();
         $this->load->library("pagination");
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->model('Post_newspaperjob_model','pnm');
        }

   public function index()
   {
    $this->load->library("pagination");
   $config['base_url'] = base_url().'news/news_cont/index';
   $config['per_page'] = 10;
   $config['num_links'] = 5;
   $config['total_rows'] =  $this->db->get('pp_jobcategories')->num_rows();
   $this->pagination->initialize($config); 
   $data['query'] = $this->db->get('pp_jobcategories',$config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(3));  
   $this->load->view('newspapers/news',$data);
 }
}
```

my model code :

```
public function getallcategories()
    {
        $query = $this->db->query('select * from pp_jobcategories');
        return $query->result();
    }
```

my view code :

```
<?php
foreach($query->result() as $row){
  echo "<p>" . $row->j_name . "</p>";
}
?>
<?php  echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>
```

Comment: hi, if you change this `$config['per_page'] = 10;` to `$config['per_page'] = 2;` can you see hte links?

Comment: damn ,!!!!!!!!!! how stupid i am :/

Comment: you just save my life bro xD thanks

Comment: Try this way https://www.sitepoint.com/pagination-with-codeigniter/ also you may need to set some routes in config/routes.php

Comment: what will be the possible route , i have an error here when i click on second page of pagination record wont change only index url change